# Change Date column to DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to change the `EventDate` column data type from `Date` to `Datetime`. When I tried to do it, it failed to save the change with message

> Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following table to be dropped & recreated. ....

Is there a way that it can be don't with dropping the table? If I drop the table then I will have another issue to deal with  when I importing the data as `EventID` is based on `auto increment` & ID can't be changed.

Any solution to this issue in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: This error comes from the visual designer - use straight T-SQL instead: `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName ALTER COLUMN EventDate DATETIME NULL` (or `NOT NULL` - whatever you need). This will work just fine, in place, no dropping of the table needed....

Comment: That make more sense, sometime it is better to be old school boy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps should help you.

To change this option,

1. Tools menu
2. click Options
3. Designers
4. Select Table and Database Designers
5. **Clear** the `check box Prevent saving changes that require the table to
   be re-created`.

Comment: I remember it, I had done same at least 4 years back... Getting old... Thanks anyways... Anything that i need to know about this as this must be their for some reason.... +1